# Can you use Google Charts within your paid IOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, charts

Reading their stuff hurts my brain!  Has anyone crossed this road?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an attorney look at it and the conclusion he came to was that if the app was not free, we could not use their API. I've heard of people getting a for-profit account with Google for using other services (routing, specifically), but I have not tried that approach yet.

Comment: You may want to evaluate HighCharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) if you're going to end up having to pay licensing. Their stuff works pretty well on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

> Reading their stuff hurts my brain!

What were you reading?

The [Google API ToS](http://code.google.com/apis/terms/index.html) seems pretty straightforward. I don't see anything there that specifically prohibits use in commercial apps. There's a line in there about some APIs being offered under an open source license, and that license trumping provisions of the ToS, but I don't see any indication of that being the case for the chart API.

Of course, I am not a lawyer, and more importantly I'm not *your* lawyer. If you need legal advice, get it from someone qualified and paid to protect your interests.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, other wise they wouldn't publish the API.

They do reserve the right to jam advertising into their charts.

[edit] From Google's page: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/
"Google chart tools are powerful, simple to use, and free."
That seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Although I do not know about this particular case - the idea that if an API is published anyone can use it for any purpose is false. Before using any API the license should be read and understood as there are APIs that forbid commercial use.

Comment: clearly wrong answer.  why would you answer when you don't know?

Comment: Before I answered, I read the terms of use like I read code, line-by-painstaking-line: http://code.google.com/apis/terms/index.html.  Did you read it?